# Trigonometric ratios proof problems

Tags: trigonometry

If $(1+\cos A)(1+\cos B)(1+\cos C)=(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C)$ then prove that each side $=\pm \sin A\sin B\sin C$

I didn't get any idea even to start the first step.

Comment: Here is a reference for Mathjax to type math formulas: http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Hint: Try using double angle formulas: $1+\cos A=2\cos^2(A/2)$ and $1-\cos A=2\sin^2 (A/2)$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Squaring both sides is equivalent to do the following
$$(1+\cos A)(1+\cos B)(1+\cos C)(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C)=(1-\cos A)(1-\cos B)(1-\cos C)(1+\cos A)(1+\cos B)(1+\cos C)$$
and using that $1-\cos^2 A=\sin^2 A$ we get
$$\sin^2 A\sin^2 B\sin^2 C=\sin^2 A\sin^2 B\sin^2 C$$
hence the result.